# How to set profile picture in robot framework

Tags: windows, robotframework, profile-picture

How to set profile picture in robot  framework. I have to select a picture in windows prompt and the same needs to updated in the web application as profile picture. Any one help me on the above request with example

Comment: Is "setting a profile picture" uploading a jpg/png file, and the "windows prompt" the standard OS control to select a file to be uploaded?

Comment: Can you please provide some more context on what it you want to achieve. Please include a [mcve] of what you're working and the observed and expected results. This will allows us to help you better.

Comment: share the html of the element used to upload profile picture?

Comment: @Todor -  Yes .It is something like, clicking on a link, prompts users to select an image. Once selected and "Ok' button is cliked, the same image should shown as  profile pic .. This is the scenario. choose file keyword will not help in this case

Comment: Do share why it won't help - add the relevant snippets of the html, and the code you're trying with. Without them it's a guessing game, hardly anyone will be able to help you.